# How to prove that this sets is subspaces or not?

Tags: linear-algebra

I need to prove whether or not these sets are subspaces in $\mathbb{R}^3$ or in $\mathbb{R}^n$(last example).

$U_1 = \{(x,y,z) \in \Bbb R^3 \mid x=y\lor x=-y\}$
$U_2 = \{(x,y,z) \in \Bbb R^3 \mid xy=0\}$
$U_3 = \{(x,y,z) \in \Bbb R^3 \mid x=z=1\}$
$U_4 = \{(x_1,\dots,x_n) \in \Bbb R^n \mid x_1 = x_2 = \cdots = x_n = n\}$

I know that a subset is a subspace if it satisfies 3 rules:

1. The vector $(0,0,0)$ must be in the subset,
2. it is closed under addition, i.e., $u+v \in W$,
3. it is closed under scalar multiplication

But when I try to apply these rules to the above examples, I get stuck. How do I apply rules on real examples like the ones I've written above?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: I have fixed the formatting on $U_4$; please do the same for the other spaces.  By the way, the code for the symbol ∨ is `\vee`.

Comment: For your last example, have you tried applying rule 1?

Comment: It does not make much sense that the question was to "prove that this sets is subspaces".  I suspect that the question was to either "prove that these sets are subspaces **or** prove that they are not subspaces".  After all, none of the sets that you have shown are subspaces.

Comment: It is actually much quicker to show that a subset is **not** a subspace.  In particular, all you need is one example where a rule (from the rules 1,2,3) is broken.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom One can also use the command `\lor` ("Logic OR") for the symbol $\lor$. Makes more sense in this particular context, and goes great together with `\land` $\land$ and `\lnot` $\lnot$.

Comment: @Arthur I always forget about that, thanks.

Comment: Note that strictly speaking, rule 1 is superfluous, as it is already implied by rule 3 (just multiply by $0$). However it can indeed be used to very quickly rule out the subspace condition for two of the sets.

Comment: @celtschk So if set containts constants like 1 or n,or other real number, that set can't be subset because of rule 1?

Comment: @ZebiniBaG: I guess you mean the right thing, but as you formulated it, I can give you a counterexample: $\{(x,y,z\in\mathbb R^3|x=1x\}$ contains the constant $1$, but actually gives the full space (since the condition is obviously always fulfilled), which of course is a subspace if itself. BTW, for $U_4$ the case $n=0$ has to be considered separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. $(1,1,0), (1,-1,0) \in U_1$. Is  $(1,1,0)+ (1,-1,0) \in U_1$ ?
2. $(1,0,0), (0,1,0) \in U_2$. Is  $(1,0,0)+(0,1,0) \in U_2$ ?
3. $(1,0,1) \in U_3.$ Is $2 \cdot (1,0,1) \in U_3 $ ?
4. Is $(0,0,...,0) \in U_4 ?$

Comment: It may be helpful to OP if you cite which rules you're referencing as well since you're framing this as an answer and not a hint.

Comment: @ Derek: a blind man sees: 1. and 2. concern rule 2; 3. concerns rule 3 and 4. concerns rule 1.  I am framing my response as an answer-hint or as a hint-answer. Are you satisfied ?